# Visual Studio Code - display pending changes for file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've noticed that VS Code does a great job of showing merge conflicts in a file when doing a merge resolution in git.  It highlights the affected rows, and provides buttons to select the multiple parts of a conflict, etc.

I've also noticed that the file explorer panel shows files which have pending modifications in git with an "M" marker.  Also, the mini-map of the file on the far right shows highlights for the lines that are changed.

Q: I want to see the actual before-and-after similar to how the merge conflict resolution works. Is there a way to enable this view? (Maybe an extension for it?)

Comment: you don't mean: select the modified file in the SCM tab, it will show the changes compared to the last commit (or maybe the staged version)

Comment: @rioV8 - actually that is pretty much exactly what I wanted. I didn't realize that view could be editable (it isn't if the file is staged.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for an extension that does this?

What I am currently using is GitLens, which lets me diff between versions and provides a whole suite of features. To install your own preferred Git extension, all you have to do is 1) go to the extensions tab, 2) type in git 3) install your selected Git extension. I've provided a picture below

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Thanks - sorry I never replied, the built-in SCM view works for me without GitLens once I realized I could edit unstaged changes.  I did try GitLens, but have found the standard behavior + GitGraph suits me, though that's purely a personal preference. YMMV.

Comment: @Brad all good, glad you found something that fits for you :)